# python pandas dataframe to list string error

Tags: python, pandas

I am relatively new to pandas and now trying to convert pandas DataFrame rows to lists of strings.

It works well, however the strings in the original DataFrame are strangely modified in the list, as some append an "L" character for some reason.

I appreciate your help very much..

```
>>data=pd.DataFrame(Data)
>>for r in data.iterrows():
>>  r[1].tolist()

>>r[1]
a          16593
b          15
c          179.069
d          110000
e          5906
Name: 0, dtype: object

>>r[1].tolist()
[16593L, 15.0, 179.068851, 110000.0, 5906L]
```

In fact I figured out, that the numbers that append an L are integers, for floats it works..

Comment: What is your requirement for the output string format?  If you want comma separated, simply use `df.to_csv()`.  `L` means `large integer'

Comment: Ok thanks, just figured that the L stands for integer. I am parsing the rows of the data frame to extract some data and store them in different dictionarys. Is there a way to omit the "L" though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every column in the DataFrame has a specific "type" associated with it.

Typically this usually means they are of type "string", "int", or "float".

Right now, your .tolist() call converts the row into a list, but it doesn't necessarily change the type of all the values into a string.

When you type a list into the console, Python uses the "repr" method to find a string representation of the list.  This involves putting in the brackets and calling "repr" on each of the elements.  This is slightly different than casting the value to a string, which is done with the "str" method.

You can test this out for yourself:

```
# For regular ints, repr and str do the same thing
a = 5
str(a)  #'5'
repr(a) #'5'

# The L means it's a *long*, basically an int with a higher max-value
a = 5L
str(a)  #'5'
repr(a) #'5L'
```

*Note, this isn't the case in Python 3 all ints are automatically 'long', resulting in no L as it would be redundant.

So, in the end, if you really want to convert your list of various types (float, int, str, depending on each column) to strings, you could use something like this:

```
my_list = [str(x) for x in my_list]
```

However, if you plan on doing some processing using these numbers, it's better to just leave them as their numerical type rather than convert back and forth to string.